# Airbus a380 fuel system

Tags: fuel-systems

Does the aibus a380 has center tank compare with a320,in this picture above,it shows that it has 11 tanks including the wings and the elevator while many aircraftshas together with the center tank (i mean that :eg the a320 ,the fuel are in the wings and cantre tank which is in the centre of the aircraft

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't understand what you're asking, can you include a link to the picture that you mentioned? That would probably help to make your question clearer. And the [tour] may be helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: This post from Capt. Dave might answer your question: https://www.google.com/amp/s/captaindave.aero/2017/09/07/the-a380-fuel-system/amp/